# Nested loop interrupting unexpectedly while scanning a list

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python 2.7 (been coding for only 4-5 months irregularly) and I think I am stuck into a misunderstanding on how nested loops works.

The goal is examining the strings of a file, loaded into a list via `readlines()`, and extracting certain blocks of information.

After loading the .txt file as above, I begin with the following:

```
for index, line in enumerate(conf_remoto):
    if 'string1' in line or 'string2' in line:
        temp_int_list = []  # initialize list
        temp_int_list[:] = [] # clean list
        temp_int_list.append(line) # append the entire line matching
        tempindex = index+1 # temporary counter, to start examining next element
        scanned_list = block_scan(tempindex, conf_remoto) # call the scanning function and pass the relevant data

def block_scan(tempindex, conf_remoto):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list[:] = []
    for i in range(tempindex, len(conf_remoto)): #loop to examine next lines
        print "Examining" + conf_remoto[i] #Cosmetic to show where I am in the loop
        print "Counter = " + str(i)
        if 'string3' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'string4' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'backup peer' in str(conf_remoto[i]):
            temp_list.append(str(conf_remoto[i])) # if any of these is found, append the entire element/string
        if 'stringbreak' in str(conf_remoto[i]): #stop the loop once you find that
            return temp_list
```

In other words:

1. I begin by loading a `.txt` file into a list, so that each element of the list contains a line of the txt (via `readlines()`)
2. The "for index, line in enumerate(name_list)" starts scanning the entire list looking for two strings (string1 or string2) in each element
3. When one of the strings is found, I invoke `block_scan()` and pass it the entire list and the position in the list where the string1/2 was matched +1, so as to make `block_scan()` begin from the next position/line in the list
4. `block_scan()` starts a `for` loop, from the position/line where string1/2 was matched, until the end of list.
5. If `block_scan()` finds any of the desired strings3/4/5 in the element `list[i]`, it appends the entire line to a temporary list, which will be returned to the caller only when a certain "stop" string is found in the list, effectively ending the loop.

Simply put, my goal is to scan a file with a loop to find all the occurrences of a certain string1/2, the scan all the lines between the said occurrence and the next first occurrence of string1/2, and fish certain lines out of the block of lines contained between the two occurrences of string1/2.

The present code doesn't seem to work, as the print statement show me that the loop within `block_scan()` scans only the next element/line in the list and not all the lines until the next occurrence of string1/2.

I don't understand why the loop inside `block_scan()` should stop at the first line, as it's a loop contained in a different function. I don't understand why (if that's the case) the primary loop is influencing its behavior.

Comment: Hello. Please check your indentation. Also, can you provide some example data - e.g. if conf_remoto is ['foo', 'bar'], then expected output is... and real output is...

Comment: When reading in the file did you use:    conf_remoto = file.readlines()      ?

Comment: What's the point of "cleaning" `temp_int_list` right after initializing it? And what do you need it for anyway, as you never seem to use it?

Comment: Thanks I think the indentation should be better now. @Sharku yes I used with open (filepath, 'r') as myfile , conf_remoto = myfile.readlines(). At Lorenzo it's a configuration file, so you might have lines such as 1) interface x/y 2) description blah 3) interface x/z

Comment: @tobias_k indeed it's a trick I use to make sure a temporary list is cleaned every time the function is invoked, because I am not quite sure the content of the list will be disposed of after the function has ended. It might be redundant, but better safe than sorry until I get more knowledgeable about the behavior of list/objects.

Comment: @giangi75 But then, shouldn't you invoke `tmp[:] = []` at the _end_ of the function, and not right after initializing the list? Anyway, let me assure you it is not necessary (and does not have much effect) either way.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your code is weak and will not work, but indentation you provide is so messy that it is impossible to get out what you are searching to do.

Take this loop:

```
for i in range(tempindex, len(conf_remoto)): 
    if 'string3' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'string4' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'backup peer' in str(conf_remoto[i]):
        temp_list.append(str(conf_remoto[i])) 
        if 'stringbreak' in str(conf_remoto[i]): 
             return temp_list
```

This is different from:

```
for i in range(tempindex, len(conf_remoto)): 
    if 'string3' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'string4' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'backup peer' in str(conf_remoto[i]):
        temp_list.append(str(conf_remoto[i])) 
    if 'stringbreak' in str(conf_remoto[i]): 
        return temp_list
```

In both cases, what is the default return value, if the expected sequence {'string3' ... 'stringbreak'} has not been found?

EDIT: 
Thanks for correcting the indentation. Let's try to establish a common example

```
#Dummy configuration file
Introduction

Il y a un an à peu près, qu’en faisant à la Bibliothèque royale des 
recherches pour mon histoire de Louis XIV, je tombai par hasard sur les 
Mémoires de M. d’Artagnan, imprimés – comme la plus grande partie des 
ouvrages de cette époque, où string1 les auteurs tenaient à dire la
vérité sans aller faire un tour plus ou moins long à la Bastille – à 
Amsterdam, chez Pierre Rouge. Le titre me séduisit : je les emportai chez 
moi, avec la permission de M. le conservateur ; bien entendu, je les dévorai.

string3 Mon intention n’est pas de faire ici une analyse de ce curieux 
ouvrage, et je me contenterai d’y renvoyer ceux de mes lecteurs qui 
apprécient les tableaux d’époques. Ils y trouveront des portraits crayonnés 
de main de maître ; et, quoique les esquisses soient, pour la plupart du 
temps, tracées stringbreak sur des portes de caserne et sur des murs de 
cabaret, ils n’y reconnaîtront pas moins, aussi ressemblantes que dans 
l’histoire de M. Anquetil, les images de Louis XIII, d’Anne d’Autriche, 
de Richelieu, de Mazarin et de la plupart des courtisans de l’époque.
```

Your posted program yields:

```
['string3 Mon intention n\xe2\x80\x99est pas de faire ici une analyse de ce curieux \n']
```

(I used a french locale and a french text so the way in which accented chars are displayed might change, this is irrelevant)

Could you please specify what would you expect as 'correct output' on this example?

EDIT 2

This answer tries not to only to answer to your question, but also to 
teach you how to build a significant test case that is so simple to be shared by all people. In your private message you specified the expected output for a different case, not covered by the previous example. So let's include in it right now (I cleaned french locale chars). Copy and paste this text and save it as a text file.

```
#Dummy configuration file
Introduction

Il y a un an a peu pres, qu'en faisant a la Bibliotheque royale des 
recherches pour mon histoire de Louis XIV, je tombai par hasard sur les 
Mémoires de M. d'Artagnan, imprimés – comme la plus grande partie des 
ouvrages de cette époque, ou string1 les auteurs tenaient a dire la
verite sans aller faire un tour plus ou moins long a la Bastille – a 
Amsterdam, chez Pierre Rouge. Le titre me seduisit : je les emportai chez 
moi, avec la permission de M. le conservateur ; bien entendu, je les 
devorai.

string3 Mon intention n'est pas de faire ici une analyse de ce curieux 
ouvrage, et je me contenterai d'y renvoyer ceux de mes lecteurs qui 
apprecient les tableaux d'epoques. Ils y trouveront des portraits crayonnes 
de main de maitre ; et, quoique les string4 esquisses soient, pour la 
plupart du temps, tracees stringbreak sur des portes de caserne et sur des 
murs de cabaret, ils n'y reconnaîtront pas moins, aussi ressemblantes que 
dans l'histoire de M. Anquetil, string4 les images de Louis XIII, d'Anne 
d'Autriche, de Richelieu, de Mazarin et de la plupart des courtisans de 
l'epoque.
```

My code is:

```
with open('testme_nested.txt', 'r') as textfile:
    conf_remoto = textfile.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(conf_remoto):
    #print line
    if 'string1' in line or 'string2' in line:
        print '>>>>*'
        temp_int_list = []  # initialize list
        temp_int_list.append(line) # append the entire line matching
        tempindex = index+1 # temporary counter, to start examining next element
        scanned_list = block_scan(tempindex, conf_remoto) # call the scanning function and pass the relevant data
        print 'Actually I found this block:'
        print scanned_list

def block_scan(tempindex, conf_remoto):
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(tempindex, len(conf_remoto)): #loop to examine next lines
        print "Examining" + conf_remoto[i] #Cosmetic to show where I am in the loop
        print "Counter = " + str(i)
        if 'string3' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'string4' in str(conf_remoto[i]) or 'backup peer' in str(conf_remoto[i]):
            temp_list.append(str(conf_remoto[i])) # if any of these is found, append the entire element/string
        if 'stringbreak' in str(conf_remoto[i]): #stop the loop once you find that
            return temp_list
```

When I run the code on this file, I get:

> Actually I found this block:
>   ["string3 Mon intention n'est pas de faire ici une analyse de ce curieux \n", 'de main de maitre ; et, quoique les string4 esquisses soient, pour la \n']

Can you please tell what's wrong with this behaviour?

Comment: The code as it is correctly finds the "stringbreak", hence it processes the entire conf_remoto list, but the output doesn't show any of the string3/4 or any other string appended to the temp_list when found. Which suggests me the code isn't processing these lines (I am absolutely sure these string3 and string4 are present in the list, obviously)

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. Assuming string3 is found in a line, the loop should append the entire line in which string3 was found into a temporary_list, whose elements will in turn be appended to another main_list at the end of the main loop. For instance, let's assume you are doing that by paragraph...you want the main loop to find the beginning of paragraph1, to start a secondary loop which will examine all the lines between the beginning of paragraph1 untile the beginning of paragraph2 is found, which would end the secondary loop. In the end it's a configuration parser that is extracting relevnt lines

Comment: Thanks for editing the indentation. In general you should avoid using indexes, better use iterators. But I still need to understand what you are expecting...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please provide the expected answer on the given example, maybe editing my answer? Not a verbal description, but the expected list, or list of lists.